# How to handle packets in netty?

Tags: java, netty, packet

Can anybody please share any tutorial which explains how to handle tcp/udp packets using netty or if somebody could explain it here. Now I have written a code to handle strings but I dont know how to decode packets and handle them in netty.

I am using netty 4.0.34

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us what you have already tried. And please consider reading [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The netty project provides many examples for many use cases to learn how to use it.

Please start reading this documentation: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example

In your specific case, you probably just need to add a handler (like you done for catching `String`) on your pipeline which catches `ByteBuf` to handle bytes packets on pipeline.